# VBscript and ADO - 3704 Operation is not allowed when the object is closed

Tags: sql, database, vbscript, ado

This function inserts a row into a SQL database and needs to return the identity number created:

```
Function WriteDatabase(backupTypeID, numImages, folderSize, success, errorMessage, strLogFileName)

    On Error Resume Next
    err.clear
    Set objConnection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    Set objRecordSet = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
    objConnection.Open "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=x.x.x.x;Initial Catalog=DB;User ID=sa;Password=xxxxxx"
    sqlquery = "INSERT INTO tblImageCopies (BackupCopyDate, BackupCopyTypeID, NumImages, ImagesFolderSize, Success, ErrorMessage) VALUES (GETDATE(), " & backupTypeID & ", " & numImages & ", " & folderSize & ", " & success & ", " & errorMessage & "); SELECT scope_identity() AS ImageCopyID;" 
    objRecordSet.Open sqlquery,objConnection
    objRecordSet.MoveFirst
    WriteDatabase = objRecordSet("ImageCopyID")
    objRecordSet.Close
    objConnection.Close
    If err.number <> 0 Then
        WriteLog "Error writing to the EHN database - " & err.number & " " & err.description, strLogFileName
    End If

End Function
```

It successfully inserts the row, but I get the error message '3704 Operation is not allowed when the object is closed.' when it tries to return the identity number in the record set. When I execute this sql query directly on the server, it works. Anyone able to help?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I do the same thing (very similar anyway). I believe that there are two sets of results coming back, one for the INSERT and then another for the SELECT. Try calling objRecordSet.NextRecordset().

Comment: Thanks Brian. Can you please advise exactly where I should put objRecordSet.NextRecordSet()? I've tried a couple of places but it's still erroring, I believe you're on the right track tho.

Comment: Ok figured it out, I had to remove objRecordset.MoveFirst and replace it with Set objRecordSet2 = objRecordSet.NextRecordset(), then change the return line to WriteDatabase = objRecordSet2("ImageCopyID"). I also had to remove objRecordset.Close. As the first statement in my compound statement does not return any rows (its an INSERT statement), objRecordset is automatically closed and cannot be closed again, thus generating the error.

Comment: [Helpful tips here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35313932/692942) about using `NextRecordset` and how to identify open recordsets.

Answer (score 6):

Use "SET NOCOUNT ON; " at the beginning of your query

Answer (score 1):

I received the exact error, and managed to track it down to a PRINT statement that I had left in my SQL Server stored procedure. Once I commented the PRINT statement, the Recordset returned the results without error.