# runtime error 3704 on a opened object

Tags: sql-server, excel, vba

I am struggling with this situation

I have a query that when i run in MSSQL server management studio it gives me 18 rows, it it stored in a cell. The database is connected to a live server and we would like to create Excel dashboards out of them so it get refreshed with live data and create graph etc....

***** EDIT *****

I tried a very simple query and it works i can get for example

select max(datetime)from table and i do have the latest sync.

The thing is: my query has

1) A Declared table for validation
2) A temporary table "with table as( ) ;" that sorts all data and rank them with some filtering "RowNumber" that is called later in with a where statement that take only some row numbers to avoid repeats

I think that in between the connection must close, can it be?

---

Normally this code works out but for this server i get:

"runtime error 3704 operation is not allowed when the object is closed"

I've searched the forum and the google with no luck

```
Dim con As ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Dim query As String
Set con = New ADODB.Connection
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

strCon = "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;" _
           & "Password=*******;" _
           & "Persist Security Info=True;" _
           & "User ID=********;" _
           & "Initial Catalog=*******;" _
           & "Data Source=***.**.**.**;" _
           & "Use Procedure for Prepare=1;" _
           & "Auto Translate=True;Packet Size=4096;" _
           & "Use Encryption for Data=False;" _
           & "Tag with column collation when possible=False"

con.Open (strCon)

rs.ActiveConnection = Con 'modified with suggestion below

strSQLQuery = Worksheets("Query").Range("B2").Value

rs.Open strSQLQuery
      For i = 0 To rs.Fields.Count - 1
Sheet2.Cells(1, i + 1) = rs.Fields(i).Name
Next i

Worksheets("Result").Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rs
rs.Close

Set rs = Nothing
con.Close
Set cn = Nothing
```

Can a magician help me out? because now im doing it with excel VBA as a demo but i would like to promote it to a VB tool and want to make sure it is not a server related issue.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Maybe take a look at this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1712094/vbscript-and-ado-3704-operation-is-not-allowed-when-the-object-is-closed   If not that then it would be useful to show your actual SQL (or something very close) and indicate exactly which line raises the error you're seeing.

Comment: Hi thank you, ill analyse the other question but even this does not work:  declare test table (value varchar(200),compare varchar(20))
insert test(value,compare) values
('X','Y'),
('Z','A')
;
select * from test

Comment: I can't use  the at-sign in the comments but it is used to declare my temporary table and to call it afterward, just like that it does not work in excel or SQL of course

Answer (score 3):

```
con.Open (strCon)
rs.ActiveConnection = strCon
```

should be

```
con.Open strCon
rs.ActiveConnection = con
```

ie. you should set `ActiveConnection` to the `Connection` object you just opened, not to the connection string.

Comment: Thank you for this swift answer. I've double checked the other vba and I've always used the first one and it used to work, i just change it to what you've instructed me cause it does make a lot of sense but it's the same error. My fear is, the server side do not allow to keep an active connection, could this be the case?