# getting value of newly inserted row

Tags: sql-server, vbscript

i am trying to exceute the following sql queries though vbscript

```sql
declare @approvalid int, @userId int 
insert into [ApprovalMaster] ([Active], [DateCreated]) values('true',getdate())  
set @approvalid =SCOPE_IDENTITY() 
insert into [UserTable] ([Emailid], [password], [approvalid])
values('testmail.com','password', @approvalid)
Set @userid=SCOPE_IDENTITY()
Select @userid as [Userid]
```

```vb
set rsemail=server.CreateObject("Adodb.Recordset")
rsemail.open sqlstr,con

response.write rsemail("userid")
```

and getting the following error

> ADODB.Recordset error '800a0cc1'
>   Item  cannot be found in the collection corresponding to the requested name or ordinal.

these statement are ruuning well in SQL Server management Studio
but getting the error while accessing though vbscript

Comment: check CASE maybe? `as [Userid]` vs `rsemail("userid")`

Comment: Does your SQL statement run in SSMS?

Comment: Don't be scared to add some formatting and white space to your queries so they are easier to read.

Comment: Try adding `SET NOCOUNT ON` to the start of your query, the rowcounts from the operations are likely counting as resultsets, so in your first result set of "*(1 row(s) affected)*" there is no `userid` column.

Comment: Dear  Gareth, 

Thanks for the Solution, it worked, set nocount on is the Solution, Thanks for help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VBscript and ADO - 3704 Operation is not allowed when the object is closed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1712094/vbscript-and-ado-3704-operation-is-not-allowed-when-the-object-is-closed)

Comment: @GarethD suggestion is the right solution here, without `SET NOCOUNT ON;` ADODB interprets the results of `INSERT` as empty closed recordsets. You could use `Set rsemail = rsemail.NextRecordset` and check whether it's `.State` is set to `adStateOpen` before attempting to read it, would be another option. More detail about it [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35313932/692942) *(shows how to loop checking `.State` of each recordset, until an open one is found)*.

Answer (score 2):

You can eliminate both of those variables too. No need to have multiple variables to hold a value that is only needed for the next statement. Also, adding nocount will help as Gareth suggested. Something along these lines should get you pretty close.

```sql
set nocount on;

insert into ApprovalMaster
(
    Active
    , DateCreated
) 
values
(
    'true'
    , getdate()
);

insert into UserTable
(
    Emailid
    , password
    , approvalid
)
values
(
    'testmail.com'
    , 'password'
    , SCOPE_IDENTITY()
);

Select SCOPE_IDENTITY() as userid;
```

```vb
set rsemail=server.CreateObject("Adodb.Recordset")
rsemail.open sqlstr,con

response.write rsemail("userid")
```

Comment: Dear Sean, 

Thanks for the Solution, it worked, set nocount on is the Solution, your advice of not using variables is also very good, Thanks for help

Comment: If this worked then you should consider marking this as the solution. Happy to help.

Comment: Hmm... *"adding nocount will help as Gareth suggested"*, it will do more than help, it's the fix, everything else is just fluff.

Answer (score 0):

The reason this happens is operations that do not produce a `ADODB.Recordset` but output a count are interpreted in ADODB as closed `Recordset` objects.

This means when you call

```vb
rsemail.open sqlstr,con
```

you are actually returning a closed `ADODB.Recordset` from the output count of your first `INSERT` statement not the `SELECT` as expected.

The fix is simple and [was suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43920059/getting-value-of-newly-inserted-row#comment74873911_43920059) by [@GarethD](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1048425/garethd) in the comments.

> *Try adding `SET NOCOUNT ON` to the start of your query*

There are other workarounds for this behaviour *(but setting `NOCOUNT ON` is by far the easiest)*.

You could use `NextRecordset` to return in next `ADODB.Recordset` in the query which will be the second `INSERT`, but calling it a third time will return the result of the `SELECT`.

```vb
Set rsemail = rsemail.NextRecordset
```